# How to remove home in a breadcrumb from a specific page in easy breadcrumbs and add carets for the breadcrumbs?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks, breadcrumbs

I've been using the easy breadcrumb module in Drupal 8, I enabled the option - "Include the front page as a segment in the breadcrumb" for all pages, but there are few pages for instance /custom-page where the breadcrumb trial is (Home  Custom-page) how do I remove the  home from these custom pages in .theme file or any alternate settings. Also the carets(>) are not appearing between the segments, how do we customize for the breadcrumb to display the caret.

Comment: Isn't this a block? With block visibility settings? And do you know any CSS? Do you use a custom theme?

Comment: this is a block, yes a custom theme is used, with CSS are you suggesting to hide the text?

Comment: The caret is CSS. Ah yeah thought you wanted to hide the whole block on certain pages. Can you analyse a bit what's different on the pages where the strange home appears? What do you mean by custom pages?